# passing argument to DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I need to pass some variables to `DialogFragment`, so I can perform an action. Eclipse suggests that I should use

```
Fragment#setArguments(Bundle)
```

But I don't know how to use this function. How can I use it to pass variables to my dialog?

Comment: Look at the sample code: http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/development/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentDialog.java

Answer (score 329, accepted):

Using `newInstance`

```
public static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int num) {
    MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();

    // Supply num input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("num", num);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}
```

And get the Args like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mNum = getArguments().getInt("num");
    ...
}
```

See the full example here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: Can you just set private variables on MyDialogFragment instead of using bundle?

Comment: @SIrCodealot the effect would be the same as setting variables on Activity or Fragment. If you face something that destroys and recreates the DialogDragment like rotation change, you will lose all variables.

Comment: For all those wondering why an overloaded constructor isn't used in this case, see another discussion on the topic that is highly instructive: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011808/why-use-newinstance-for-dialogfragment-instead-of-the-constructor

Comment: Took me a minute to notice that the **savedInstanceState** is not used.

Answer (score 32):

I used to send some values from my listview

**How to send**

```
mListview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Favorite clickedObj = (Favorite) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("tar_name", clickedObj.getNameTarife());
            args.putString("fav_name", clickedObj.getName());

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            TarifeDetayPopup userPopUp = new TarifeDetayPopup();
            userPopUp.setArguments(args);
            userPopUp.show(fragmentManager, "sam");

            return false;
        }
    });
```

**How to receive** inside onCreate() method of DialogFragment

```
    Bundle mArgs = getArguments();
    String nameTrife = mArgs.getString("tar_name");
    String nameFav = mArgs.getString("fav_name");
    String name = "";
```

// Kotlin upload

```
 val fm = supportFragmentManager
        val dialogFragment = AddProgFargmentDialog() // my custom FargmentDialog
        var args: Bundle? = null
        args?.putString("title", model.title);
        dialogFragment.setArguments(args)
        dialogFragment.show(fm, "Sample Fragment")
```

// receive

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            val mArgs = arguments
            var myDay= mArgs.getString("title")
        }
    }
```

Comment: The Better answer!

Comment: Thank YOU ! The Kotlin version helped.

Comment: I did the same thing with Kotlin version, but it always  null when receiving arguments.

Answer (score 9):

So there is two ways to pass values from fragment/activity to dialog fragment:-

> 1. Create dialog fragment object with make setter method and pass value/argument.
> 2. Pass value/argument through bundle.

## Method 1:

```
// Fragment or Activity 
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     DialogFragmentWithSetter dialog = new DialogFragmentWithSetter();
     dialog.setValue(header, body);
     dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DialogFragmentWithSetter");         
}


//  your dialog fragment
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    String header; 
    String body;
    public void setValue(String header, String body) {   
          this.header = header;
          this.body = body;
    }
    // use above variable into your dialog fragment
}
```

> Note:- This is not best way to do

## Method 2:

```
// Fragment or Activity 
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     DialogFragmentWithSetter dialog = new DialogFragmentWithSetter();
     
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
     bundle.putString("header", "Header");
     bundle.putString("body", "Body");  
     dialog.setArguments(bundle);
     dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DialogFragmentWithSetter");         
}


//  your dialog fragment
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    String header; 
    String body;
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
             header = getArguments().getString("header","");
             body = getArguments().getString("body","");
        }
    }
    // use above variable into your dialog fragment
}
```

> Note:- This is the best way to do.

Comment: You can even use the Gson library to pass Objects or ArrayList<Objects> as Strings in the Bundle.

Comment: @duggu, why getter and setter is not the best way to do so?

Comment: Won't method 1 loose those arguments on a configuration change AKA screen rotation?

Answer (score 5):

as a general way of working with Fragments, as JafarKhQ noted, you should not pass the params in the constructor but with a `Bundle`.

the built-in method for that in the `Fragment` class is `setArguments(Bundle)` and `getArguments()`.

basically, what you do is set up a bundle with all your `Parcelable` items and send them on.
in turn, your Fragment will get those items in it's `onCreate` and do it's magic to them.

the way shown in the `DialogFragment` link was one way of doing this in a multi appearing fragment with one specific type of data and works fine most of the time, but you can also do this manually.

Answer (score 2):

Just that i want to show how to do what do said @JafarKhQ in Kotlin for those who use **kotlin** that might help them and save theme time too:

so you have to create a **companion objet** to create new **newInstance** function

you can set the paremter of the function whatever you want.
using

```
 val args = Bundle()
```

you can set your args.

You can now use `args.putSomthing` to add you args which u give as a prameter in your newInstance function.
 `putString(key:String,str:String)` to add string for example and so on

Now to get the argument you can use 
`arguments.getSomthing(Key:String)`=> like `arguments.getString("1")`

here is a full example

```
class IntervModifFragment : DialogFragment(), ModContract.View
{
    companion object {
        fun newInstance(  plom:String,type:String,position: Int):IntervModifFragment {
            val fragment =IntervModifFragment()
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putString( "1",plom)
            args.putString("2",type)
            args.putInt("3",position)
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }

...
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        fillSpinerPlom(view,arguments.getString("1"))
         fillSpinerType(view, arguments.getString("2"))
        confirmer_virme.setOnClickListener({on_confirmClick( arguments.getInt("3"))})


        val dateSetListener = object : DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
            override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker, year: Int, monthOfYear: Int,
                                   dayOfMonth: Int) {
                val datep= DateT(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth)
                updateDateInView(datep.date)
            }
        }

    }
  ...
}
```

Now how to create your dialog you can do somthing like this in another class

```
  val dialog = IntervModifFragment.newInstance(ListInter.list[position].plom,ListInter.list[position].type,position)
```

like this for example

```
class InterListAdapter(private val context: Context, linkedList: LinkedList<InterItem> ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<InterListAdapter.ViewHolder>()
{
   ... 
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        ...
        holder.btn_update!!.setOnClickListener {
           val dialog = IntervModifFragment.newInstance(ListInter.list[position].plom,ListInter.list[position].type,position)
           val ft = (context as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            dialog.show(ft, ContentValues.TAG)
        }
        ...
    }
..

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the code above with `bundle-operate` works; Here is my decision (I don't know if it is proper code or not, but it works in my case):

```
public class DialogMessageType extends DialogFragment {
    private static String bodyText;

    public static DialogMessageType addSomeString(String temp){
        DialogMessageType f = new DialogMessageType();
        bodyText = temp;
        return f;
    };

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final String[] choiseArray = {"sms", "email"};
        String title = "Send text via:";
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(title).setItems(choiseArray, itemClickListener);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        return builder.create();
    }

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener itemClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
                case 0:
                    prepareToSendCoordsViaSMS(bodyText);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    prepareToSendCoordsViaEmail(bodyText);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
[...]
}

public class SendObjectActivity extends FragmentActivity {
[...]

DialogMessageType dialogMessageType = DialogMessageType.addSomeString(stringToSend);
dialogMessageType.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"dialogMessageType");

[...]
}
```

Comment: 1) By storing the bodyText statically, you effectively make it impossible to have two instances of this class at the same time, with different body texts. There's no reason not to store it as an instance variable instead. 2) The whole purpose of sending arguments using setArguments(Bundle) is that the OS can then re-create the fragment in case it's lost in a low memory situation etc. With your solution the fragment will be re-created, and body text will be whatever the last instance of the dialog used (since it's static).

The correct solution is to set the body text as a bundle parameter.