# How to replace a Fragment on button click of that fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity containing multiple fragments. Activity initially have fragment and in it have two buttons. Upon clicking this button I have to replace the fragment by new fragment. Each fragment has various widgets and replace the current fragment as various events.

This is my problem. How can I achieve this?

Suggest me ideas.

Comment: why can you not just change the visibility of the fragments?

Comment: Pass callback to activity and let it replace fragment. To do this just create interface with callback and implement it in Activity. Then in Fragment override onAttach(activity) function and store the interface for onClick

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can replace fragment by FragmentTransaction.

Here you go.

Make an interface.

```
public interface FragmentChangeListener 
{
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment); 
}
```

implements your Fragment holding activity with this interface.

```
public class HomeScreen extends FragmentActivity implements
        FragmentChangeListener {


         @Override
         public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();;     
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(mContainerId, fragment, fragment.toString());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.toString());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();   
    }

}
```

Call this method from Fragments like this.

//In your fragment.

```
public void showOtherFragment()
{
       Fragment fr=new NewDisplayingFragment();
             FragmentChangeListener fc=(FragmentChangeListener)getActivity();
             fc.replaceFragment(fr);
}
```

Hope this will work!

**NOTE: mContainerId is id of the view who is holding the fragments inside. 
You should override Fragment's onString() method as well.**

Comment: the question is how to call the method in the activity from the containing fragment, not what the method should look like

Comment: @MarioStoilov: Sorry, i have updated my answer, Please try it.

Comment: **You should override Fragment's onString() method as well** 
What is this means?

Comment: By Overriding onString() method, you can assigned a unique name to each fragment, like you can return "myFragment" from onString() method of fragment. Now, suppose you need to search fragment in FragmentBackStack, Then you can search it by using onString() response. which is "myFragment" string..

Comment: One more doubt. each fragments value should be available to next fragments also. How can i  pass arguments to fragment when i call ' fc.replaceFragment(fr); ' ? i used ' fragment.setArguments(args); ' . Each fragment is separate classes.

Comment: @Rashid: Here is the way to pass the arguments to fragments: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15459259/2105241

Comment: for the mContainerId, can I do fragment.getView().getId()?

Comment: Thanks you so much brother. This is what I had been looking for. And really worked well for me. Much appreciated. Good one.

Answer (score 8):

Well even I am learning android...

I solved same problem recently, "How to Change Fragment On button's click event".

```
buttonName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame1, new Homefragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
});
```

Here `frame1` is id of `FrameLayout` which have define in my DrawerLayer's XML.

So now whenever I want fragment transaction I use this code. Each time it will replace `frame1` instated of your last fragment.

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity()
        .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame1, new newfragment());
fragmentTransaction.commit()
```

Hope this will help..

Comment: Simple easily solution! Worked perfectly thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to replace a fragment on button click of that fragment:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content, new insertFragmentNameHere()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Define an interface and call it IChangeListener (or something like that) and define a method inside which will do the work (ex, `changeFragment()`) (or call another method which will do the work) for changing the fragment).
2. Make your activity implement the interface, or make an anonymous class within the activity implement it.
3. Make a paramerized constructor of your fragment, which accepts a IChangeListener parameter.
4. When initializing the fragment, pass your IChangeListener implementation (the anonymous class or the activity, implementing it)
5. Make the onClick listener of the button call the changing method of the IChangeListener.

Comment: I know that this is the recommended method. But, can you tell me the advantages of using this over just calling getActivity().changeFragment() from the fragment's onClick?

Comment: @Srikanth If you call getActivity(), you will get an object of type Activity(the base class, not your implementation) and you will have to cast it to to your implementation of the activity, which makes you dependant on this particular implementation, while when you use an Interface, the class that implements it could be everything (fragment in a fragment, fragment in a listview, etc.) and that wont bother you, so you can reuse this code for different purposes

Comment: Seems a lot cleaner and reusable that way. Thanks for clarifying. I think you need to update your answer a bit. When you use parameterized constructor for a fragment, eclipse throws a warning - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062946/why-do-i-want-to-avoid-non-default-constructors-in-fragments . Android recommends the use of onAttach(Activity) as mentioned here - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 1):

From the future 2017 and after, there exists different libraries that triggers *Events* using *Bus* and now you can use it to tell the activity when an event is trigger in a fragment that it owns.

Refer to:

[RxBus with RxJava](https://blog.metova.com/how-to-use-rxjava-as-an-event-bus/)

You can check new architectures suggested by Google

[ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel.html)

Don't use the approach in the accepted answer, get really ugly with more than 3 different events from fragments

Comment: Why do you think this will fall under Observer Pattern? I think that will be an over kill

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code it's work fine with me , inflate the layout to view , Define the buton and on click ,

```
Button btn_unstable;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);

    btn_unstable = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_unstable);
    btn_unstable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_replace, new UnstableFragment()).commit();

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
activity?.supportFragmentManager?.commit {
        replace(R.id.host_fragment, fragment)
        setReorderingAllowed(true)
        addToBackStack(fragment.toString())
    }
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager

For Kotlin, Jan 2024