# Barcode Reader/ Generator in one activity Android

Tags: android

I would like to have a barcode reader/generator in my app, preferably in one activity. For iOS i think this can  be done using a segmented view controller. How would I do this in android? Or should i just put them on two different activities?

Comment: To use barcode reader and generator you can use ZXing Lib and yes you can put both in same activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming from what I could understand from your question:

you could use a ViewPager, you can read more at http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Or if you want the look and feel of IOS segmented control, probably you could create two buttons and change fragments based on which button has been clicked.

Take a look at this (assuming you understand fragments)
[How to replace a Fragment on button click of that fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228721/how-to-replace-a-fragment-on-button-click-of-that-fragment)

Fragments are close to UIViews in IOS. If you are not well versed with fragments, this might help http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm