# onItemClick of a ListView not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have 2 fragment classes. In `Fragment1.java`,

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String favorite_message =(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                Log.d("hi","favorite" + favorite_message);
                //Populate the edit text of Fragment1
            }
        });
```

In `Fragment2.java`,

```
     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     mytext= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
     getText();
    }

    public void getText(){
     String message = mytext.getEditableText().toString();
   }
```

I want the `favorite_message` to be present in the `mytext` edittext. Since these 2 fragments are like tabs, upon `onItemClick` I want the tab position to be automatically shifted to `Fragment2` and edit text should be `favorite_message`.

How do I do this?

Comment: show your xml code

Comment: Are you using `ViewPager` for your "like tabs" ? Could you provide info about your two fragments ?

Comment: See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228721/how-to-replace-a-fragment-on-button-click-of-that-fragment

Comment: @YeLinAung Yes I have a mainactivity which has viewpager and then i have these 2 fragments as tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your viewpager of activity global as below in your Activity file where you are setting your viewpager.

```
 public static ViewPager YOUR_VIEW_PAGER;
```

Make your String global first as below in your Fragment1:

```
public static boolean isListClicked=false;
public static String favorite_message ="";

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           isListClicked=true; 
           favorite_message =(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
           //set second fragment in your viewpager by below line
           YOURACTIVITY.YOUR_VIEW_PAGER.setCurrentItem(1);
            Log.d("hi","favorite" + favorite_message);
            //Populate the edit text of Fragment1
        }
    });
```

In onCreateView of Fragment2,write as below:

```
 if (Fragment1.isListClicked){
    if(!Fragment1.favorite_message.equals(""))
      mytext.setText(Fragment1.favorite_message);

 }
```

Also add below method in your Fragment2

```
 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        if (Fragment1.isListClicked){
            if(!Fragment1.favorite_message.equals(""))
                txt.setText(Fragment1.favorite_message);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I implemented it and the view of the fragment changes correctly I mean it gets shifted to Fragment2 upon click. But the edit text does not have the favorite_message

Comment: Check my edited code in onItemClick to get your selecteditem.

Comment: Try to print Fragment1.favorite_message in your onCreateView of Fragment2 before if(!Fragment1.favorite_message.equals(""))
      mytext.setText(Fragment1.favorite_message);

Comment: Ok I did it...But there is no log coming. It comes when the fragment is created for first time after which I move to fragment1 and do onClick.

Comment: Ok also write above lines in your onResume method in Fragment2.

Comment: I tried it but still same problem... It is not coming to onResume also upon itemclick

Comment: @Mark023 Please check my edited answer, it solves your problem.:-)

Comment: Can you please tell what is OneFragment.isListClicked. Is it Fragment1.isListClicked? If yes, it shows isListClicked cannot be resolved

Comment: Yeah sorry it is Fragment1.isListClicked and add public static boolean isListClicked=false; in Fragment1 and not in activity as I edited above.

Comment: :) Happiiee Coding.

Comment: Keeping reference of `View`s in static fields is a very bad way. See this link about how a Fragment should interact with other fragments and its parent Activity - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any `Button` or `ImageButton` in your `ListView-Item`
If yes then,
this attribute has to be added to the top most layout of your `XML` where you have provided the `ListView` elements.

```
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

if not then
can you post your both classes, by the way now you must use `recyclerview`

Comment: How is this related to my question

Comment: is your onitemclicklistener working? Can you see your **favorite_message** in log

Comment: Yes it is working and i can see the message in the log

Comment: your listview is in fragment1 or in activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the fragment by using the fragment's list from fragment manager

if using support fragment manager:
getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();

if using fragment manager:
getFragmentManager();

u knw that Fragment2 is in second position in your fragment list

so you can set the text by doing this

((Fragment2)getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(1)).setText("Text");

where setText(String) is a public method you can make in Fragment2

What do you mean by tab btw ???