# How to Load WebView in Fragment class? How to load Webview in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, findviewbyid

I am trying to create a WebView in a Fragment which should be loaded. I added it already to my xml File. However, the findViewById method only works if I extend an Activity class. Is there anyway of which I can use it in Fragment as well?

I already tested the Solution from another Question, but it doesn't work.

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

public WebView PlanWebView;

public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    PlanWebView WebView = (PlanWebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.PlanWebView);
    // Unknown class: "PlanWebView";
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this please , This is the  **OneFragment** class , Webview needs a view which has to be inflated using xml

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout. fragment_one, container, false);
    mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    return view;
}
```

and **xml** for fragment_one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!
I have another problem...

How i can do a reload this WebView in a Fragment?
Without Fragments and in a single MainActivity it is very easy...

I added a menu in the MainActivity, but where must i add the public boolean for the menu? If i add this in the One_Fragment.class i get a crash after pressing the update button in the menu.

Comment: `@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuitem) {
        int id = menuitem.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.update) {
            OneFragment.this.PlanWebView.loadUrl("http://google.de");
        }
        return false;
    }`

Comment: Hello dear ,can u please explain about your new issue i am not able to get it? Do you mean you want to reload webview from the main activity?

Comment: Yes exactly. Reload from MainActivity or from One_Fragment Activity.

Comment: okay you should use interface to do that ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228721/how-to-replace-a-fragment-on-button-click-of-that-fragment

Comment: look at this and try it.

Comment: Thanks, but this solution opens the same fragment over the fragment. However, only the URL in the WebView should be reloaded by pressing the update button in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

in Fragment you can declare your variables in onCreateView method.

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

public WebView PlanWebView;

public OneFragment() {
// Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


 }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
PlanWebView  = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.PlanWebView);
return view;
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use  code below in `onCreateView` method:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(layout,container,false);

WebView webview = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);

return view;
```