# My Webview show blank in kotlin fragment why?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

my webview show blank page

this is my Activity Class.

```
class AboutFragment : BaseGreenHCMFragment() { 
    override val layoutId = R.layout.fragment_about
    override fun setupData() {}
    override fun setupView() { 
        val mWebView: WebView? = view?.findViewById(R.id.webviewdaum) as WebView
        mWebView?.loadUrl("greenhcm.com/") 
        val webSettings = mWebView?.getSettings()
        webSettings?.setJavaScriptEnabled(true) 
        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser 
        //mWebView?.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())
    }
}
```

[this is my xml & fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOE6U.png)

Comment: please write your code as text not image.

Comment: class AboutFragment : BaseGreenHCMFragment() {
    override val layoutId = R.layout.fragment_about
    override fun setupData() {}
    override fun setupView() {
            val mWebView: WebView? = view?.findViewById(R.id.webviewdaum) as WebView
            mWebView?.loadUrl("https://www.greenhcm.com/")
            val webSettings = mWebView?.getSettings()
            webSettings?.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
            // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
            //mWebView?.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())
    }
}

Comment: this is my fragment sir

Comment: I edit your question and make same your xml file as class code

Answer (score 0):

anyway check this code.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   var mywebview: WebView? = null
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       mywebview = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview)
       mywebview!!.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
           override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
               view?.loadUrl(url)
               return true
           }
       }
       mywebview!!.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/")
   }
```

}

you need WebViewClient in your code.

Comment: i am in fragment sir , can you help me ?, i am newbie in kotlin

Comment: val mywebview: WebView = view?.findViewById(R.id.webviewdaum) as WebView
        mywebview!!.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
                view?.loadUrl(url)
                return true
            }
        }
        mywebview!!.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.id/")

Comment: did you check internet permission? and can you write log?

Comment: and where is your onCreateView in fragment lifeCycle?

Comment: 2020-10-27 11:59:27.490 22171-22171/com.greenhcm.android W/ContentCatcher: Failed to notify a WebView

Comment: this is my full source code inside setupview() in fragment

Comment: override fun setupView() {
             val mywebview: WebView = view?.findViewById(R.id.webviewdaum) as WebView
                    mywebview!!.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
                            view?.loadUrl(url)
                            return true
                        }
                    }
    //errror in this
                    mywebview!!.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.id/")
            }

Comment: pleae help me sir

Comment: D/EgretLoader: The context is not activity

Comment: check this article https://stackoverflow.com/a/47322914/10778405. and just change code to Kotlin