# android send data from Activity to DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-edittext, alarm, timepicker, dialogfragment

i am trying to make a app which set a alarm according to the timepicker, i have done this but i want the edittext from the mainactivity to be put into the alert dialog which is presented when the alrm goes off.

i want to send text from mainactivity to alertdemo.

MainActivity.class

```
private void stalarm() {
    View.OnClickListener setClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            /** This intent invokes the activity DemoActivity, which in turn opens the AlertDialog window */
            Intent i = new Intent("app.com.timepicker.demoactivity");

            /** Creating a Pending Intent */
            PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), unique, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            /** Getting a reference to the System Service ALARM_SERVICE */
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            /** Getting a reference to TimePicker object available in the MainActivity */
            TimePicker tpTime = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.tp_time);

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int hour = tpTime.getCurrentHour();
            int minute = tpTime.getCurrentMinute();

            /** Creating a calendar object corresponding to the date and time set by the user */
            GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, minute);

            /** Converting the date and time in to milliseconds elapsed since epoch */
            long alarm_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

            /** Setting an alarm, which invokes the operation at alart_time */
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm_time, operation);

            /** Alert is set successfully */
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Alarm is set successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    Button btnSetAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_set_alarm);
    btnSetAlarm.setOnClickListener(setClickListener);

}
```

demoactivity.class

```
public class DemoActivity extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /** Creating an Alert Dialog Window */
    AlertDemo alert = new AlertDemo();

    /** Opening the Alert Dialog Window. This will be opened when the alarm goes off */
    alert.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "AlertDemo");

}
```

alertdemo.class

```
public class AlertDemo extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /** Turn Screen On and Unlock the keypad when this alert dialog is displayed */
    getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

    /** Creating a alert dialog builder */
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    /** Setting title for the alert dialog */
    builder.setTitle("alarm " );

    /** Setting the content for the alert dialog */
    builder.setMessage("An Alarm by AlarmManager");

    /** Defining an OK button event listener */
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            /** Exit application on click OK */
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });

    /** Creating the alert dialog window */
    return builder.create();
}

/** The application should be exit, if the user presses the back button */
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getActivity().finish();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is send the contents of your EditText to the DialogFragment to do something with that information, you can use the `setArguments()` functionality of Fragments. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459209/passing-argument-to-dialogfragment) covers a good pattern for doing this.

Ultimately, you'll want to create a `newInstance` for your DialogFragment with a String argument.  That argument is put in the fragment's arguments bundle in `newInstance`, and accessed when needed later in the fragment's life cycle.

When you call your `newInstance` simply do `DialogFragment.newInstance(editText.getText()` to get the DialogFragment you want to pass to your fragment manager.