# Android : Can't pass the data from Fragment to DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

Hi I'am trying to pass the data from Fragment to DialogFragment.

This is the code I have written in Fragment in ListView onClick()

```
meetingdialog = new MeetingFragment(proj1);
                         event = cts.get(position);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context,meetingdialog.getClass());
                        intent.putExtra("event_id", event.eve_id);
                        intent.putExtra("proj_id", proj1.p_id);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
```

And this is the way I'am getting the value in DialogFragment

```
Intent in = new Intent();
    eid = in.getStringExtra("event_id");
    pid = in.getStringExtra("proj_id");
```

I'am getting null value in eid and pid. How can i get those values in DialogFragment? Please help me.

Comment: what is this meetingdialog.getClass()

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar It's an object of DialogFragment class

Comment: This is absolutely not the way to deal with Fragments. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459209/passing-argument-to-dialogfragment

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
eid = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("event_id");
pid = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("proj_id");
```

Comment: The method getIntent() is undefined for the type ModifyEventFragment

Comment: updated my code and ModifyEventFragment is extendsFragment or not

Comment: it extends DialogFragment

Comment: event.eve_id and eid  are same type or not i also check using getActivity() u can get the object of intent class