# Pass item[] to DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I am trying to pass the `String []` items of my Dialog Fragment when the activity is running, as this String is updated and its values, which are showing the `DialogFragment` are updated and can not always choose the same.
I have read this topic: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459209/passing-argument-to-dialogfragment) but I think that's not exactly what I need.
I know someone help me?

This is mi class DialogoSeleccion wich extends DialogFragment:

```
public class DialogoSeleccion extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final String[] items = {"Español", "Inglés", "Francés"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = 
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setTitle("Selección")
        .setMultiChoiceItems(items, null, 
                new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.i("Dialogos", "Opción elegida: " + items[item]);
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

And this is the code of the main class:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
DialogoSeleccion dialogo = new DialogoSeleccion();
dialogo.show(fragmentManager, "tagSeleccion");
```

He probado a poner `String[]` items como una variable de la clase DialogoSeleccion y luego acceder desde el main de la forma:

```
public class DialogoSeleccion extends DialogFragment {
    private String[] opciones;
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    ...

String[] opciones = {"1","2"}
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
DialogoSeleccion dialogo = new DialogoSeleccion();
dialogo.items= opciones[];
dialogo.show(fragmentManager, "tagSeleccion");
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help

Comment: use setArguments. Bundle has the putStringArray method which is what you need

Comment: @Blackbelt thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a bundle when committing the DialogoFragment

```
Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray(A_KEY,mArray);
DialogoSeleccion dialogo = new DialogoSeleccion();
dialogo.setArguments(bundle);
```

And then you retrieve the bundle arguments in your Dialog

```
String[] array = bundle.getArguments().getStringArray(A_KEY);
```