# android passing data to dialogBox

Tags: android, string, dialog, bundle, send

Hello I am a beginner in android programing and I have problem with sending data from MainActivity to my dialogBox.I have to ask here because I tried for a long time without success.

In MainActivity.class I use onOptionsItemSelected method to create dialog box from DialogBoxSettings.class.

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    String title = (String) item.getTitle(); // I set my title
    Bundle savedInstanceState = new Bundle();
    savedInstanceState.putString("dialogBoxSettingsTitle", title);

    DialogBoxSettings newFragment = new DialogBoxSettings();
    newFragment.setArguments(savedInstanceState);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialogBoxSettings");

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

In DialogBoxSettings in method onCreateDialog I create my dialog

```
public class DialogBoxSettings extends DialogFragment {

private static final String TAG = DialogBoxSettings.class.getSimpleName();

EditText mEditTextDialogBoxService;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_box_settings, null);
    builder.setView(view);
    //builder.setMessage(title);

    mEditTextDialogBoxService = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogBoxService);

    builder.setPositiveButton(getResources().getText(R.string.dialogBoxSettingsPositiveButton), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "POSITIVE button");
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getText(R.string.dialogBoxSettingsNegativeButton), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "NEGATIVE button");
        }
    });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

All this works fine besides the fact that I do not know how to pass title to onCreateDialog method. I now that I need to use Bundle for this, but I really try everything and failed for now, so if someone help me I would be very grateful. So far I have tried to do something like this but I have not succeeded [Pass item[] to DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988524/pass-item-to-dialogfragment)

THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your dialog Fragment :

```
public class DialogBoxSettings extends DialogFragment {

private static final String TAG = DialogBoxSettings.class.getSimpleName();

EditText mEditTextDialogBoxService;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

***final String title = getArguments().getString("dialogBoxSettingsTitle");***


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_box_settings, null);
    builder.setView(view);
***builder.setTitle(title);***
    //builder.setMessage(title);

    mEditTextDialogBoxService = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogBoxService);

    builder.setPositiveButton(getResources().getText(R.string.dialogBoxSettingsPositiveButton), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "POSITIVE button");
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getText(R.string.dialogBoxSettingsNegativeButton), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "NEGATIVE button");
        }
    });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: Most Welcome :)