# Open Image in dialog after click

Tags: android, image, dialog

Is it possibile to open image in dialog without creating new activity?

If yes how to transfer this photo to a dialog.

Comment: you can pass the image url to DialogFragment using Bundle

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15459259/6142219

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder ImageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
ImageDialog.setTitle("Title");
ImageView showImage = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
ImageDialog.setView(showImage);

ImageDialog.setNegativeButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
    {   
    }
});
ImageDialog.show();
```

Comment: But how to transfer image to a dialog?

Comment: Your image is placed in drawable or it is a Url

Comment: My image is a Url