# Is there way to putExtra into a dialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, dialog

I'm building an app the captures the data of a listitem by clicking on it. I'm able to pass the MarketID through an intent however I want to pass it using a dialog to change specific data. So how do I .putExtra for a dialog. Thanks

Here's the code

```
int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        int marketID = markets.get(position).getMarketID();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SuperMarketRaterDialog superMarketRaterDialog = new SuperMarketRaterDialog();
        superMarketRaterDialog.putExtra("marketID", marketID);
        superMarketRaterDialog.show(fragmentManager,"RateMarket");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [passing argument to DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459209/passing-argument-to-dialogfragment)

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious approach might be, to pass it into the `DialogFragment` constructor:

```
SuperMarketRaterDialog superMarketRaterDialog = new SuperMarketRaterDialog(marketID);
```

Unless using the navigation component, there's no way to pass navigation `Arguments`.