# MaterialAlertDialog not showing items from Room DB

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, kotlin-coroutines

I want to show a list of Strings in a MaterialAlertDialog. I'm loading them from Room Db within a suspended function and use a callback to set the items in the DialogFragment. Here the code:

**PlayerDao.kt**

```kotlin
@Dao
interface PlayerDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE playable = 1")
    suspend fun getPlayableCharacters():List<PlayerEntity>

}
```

**PlayerRepository.kt**

```kotlin
@Singleton
class PlayerRepository @Inject constructor(private val db: AppDatabase) {

    suspend fun getPlayableCharacters():List<Player>{
        return db.playerDao().getPlayableCharacters().map {
            Player.fromEntity(it)
        }
    }

}
```

**WelcomeViewModel.kt**

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class WelcomeViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: PlayerRepository) : ViewModel() {
    
fun loadPlayableChars(onResult: (List<Pair<String, Int>>) -> Unit) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val result: List<Pair<String, Int>> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                repository.getPlayableCharacters().map {
                    Pair(it.name, it.getLevel())
                }
            }
            onResult(result)
        }
    }

}
```

**WelcomeFragment.kt**

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class WelcomeFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        _binding = FragmentWelcomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        binding.loadCharButton.setOnClickListener {
            SelectCharacterDialogFragment().show(childFragmentManager, "SelectCharacterDialogFragment")
        }

        return binding.root
    }

}
```

**SelectCharacterDialogFragment.kt**

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SelectCharacterDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {
    val viewModel: WelcomeViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val itemsToShow = arrayOf<String>()
        val items = mutableListOf<Pair<String, Int>>()
        val dialogBuilder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext())
            .setTitle("Choose a character")


        viewModel.loadPlayableChars { list ->
            Log.d("DIALOG", "in Callback: $list")
            items += list

            val itemsToShow = items.map {
                "${it.first}: ${it.second}"
            }.toTypedArray()


            dialogBuilder.setItems(itemsToShow) { dialog, which ->
                when (which) {
                    0 -> Log.d("Dialog", "$which")
                    else -> Log.d("Dialog", "$which")
                }
            }

        }
        Log.d("DIALOG", "Returning dialog")
        return dialogBuilder.create()

    }

}
```

The log output inside the callback tells me that the data is available. But to late. The method has already returned when the callback is executed:

```
D/DIALOG: Returning dialog
I/System.out: SQL: SELECT * FROM players WHERE playable = 1
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: AlertDialog without items]

What did I wrong? What is the best practice to make a one-shot request to show items inside an AlertDialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour occurs because your code inside `onCreateDialog` does not wait for the result of `viewModel.loadPlayableChars` (which operates async) but continue and returns the created dialog.

As you should not wait for the result of `viewModel.loadPlayableChars` on the `MainThread` and then return the `Dialog`, I would load the data and open the `Dialog` within the callback passing the loaded data to the dialog.

[How to pass data to a DialogFragment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459209/passing-argument-to-dialogfragment)